Can I create a smart contract contract that can extract LP fees from renounced ownership crypto?
I hope all is well with you wherever you are 
So I'm trying to figure out something for a project.
Scenario:

Launching a new token to Airdrop to people who qualify certain criteria.

Create a liquidity pool on a DEX (wish to renounce ownership/lock liquidity for consumer confidence)

Wish to automate a function to pull LP rewards on a scheduled basis to Airdrop to wallets that qualify certain criteria.


Is it possible to create a smart contract that can:

pull LP rewards? Pay least fees as possible
distribute those LP fees on a scheduled basis to set list of wallets.
have the above run on a scheduled automated basis.

Thank you in advance for your responses. I look forward to hearing back from the experts!
